# 2 Sample T-Test vs 1-Factor ANOVA

Tags: anova, t-test

Is it more advantageous to conduct a 2-sample T-test or single factor ANOVA when determining statistical significance between the means of two independent groups? I have run sample tests on mock data and they are yielding the same p-values. I am also noticing that the t-value from the T-test is always the root of the F-value from the ANOVA.. Could someone explain this relationship?

Thank you.

Comment: ANOVA on two groups is exactly the same as an equal-variance t-test on two groups.